# Theme assets not loaded in CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

in CakePHP (4.1.3) I've set up a theme in my plugins dir. There is just one view and I try to load a script within the plugin.

I have all correct folders:

```
/plugins/Theme/templates/Feeds/show.php
/plugins/Theme/webroot/js/feed.js
```

I try to load the script by including it in the view show.php:

```
echo $this->Html->script('feed');
```

It correctly generates path:

```
/theme/js/feed.js
```

But the framework doesn't interpret the path correctly, it says that I am missing controller (Theme).

Any ideas what could gone wrong very much appreciated.

Comment: Does your theme plugin have routing set up?

Comment: It's just a theme. Not plugin. Themes are placed in plugin folder. I cast it by calling $this->viewBuilder()->setTheme('Theme'); in controller.

Comment: Every theme is a plugin, but not every plugin is a theme.

Comment: Do you have the assset middleware loaded [**in your `Application::midlleware()` method**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.1.1/src/Application.php#L75-L78)?

Comment: I do have it loaded. Added to the queue.